# approach for storing image in sql database

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets

i am trying to store image in sql on server. Later i want to make these image available for download. Which approach is good:

1. By uploading image and saving path.
   or
   2.By converting image to base64 and then storing as BLOB type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 1):

If the `security` is main concern then store image in `DB` in `blob`, or if if it is not much sensitive then store it in specific directory then store it's path in `DB`.

Because `DB storage give it extra security`.

If we store it on directory then someone can access it if they have tried some trick to access the directory.

So, and if we store it on directory then `proper handling` of file should be done.
Because if someone upload file then again other person store it wit `same name` then possibility of file `overwrite`.

So you can do something like that take `2 fields` in table `one is original name` and `one is new name that have original name plus the timestamp of file upload` and in directory store it with that `new name`.

and if you are storing it in DB then doesn't need this extra work.

And yes bifurcation of images in directory also tough, suppose in one year so many file will be stored in it so indexing plus accessing become cumbersome work.
So apply some mechanism so at some time of interval you can separate images.

Comment: Oh my pleasure.. If solved your question then accept anyone so other people will not see your solved one problem bhai ji.. Keep smiling.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a tradeoff, and it also depends a lot on your network connection, I'd go for keeping the images in the cloud and just keeping a key in the database.

It would shrink the disk usage a lot , possibly even allowing the entire database to be cached into ram, thus balancing the extra time the process would spend retrieving the relevant info from the network